# Android AdMob cannot set into testing mod

Tags: android

the line  adView.setTesting(true);   gives e a error saying the method does not exits,
code blocksetTesting 
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e10cb6b18825");
        ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e10cb6b18825");

```
    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.setTesting(true);

    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with the `setTesting()` api call.  In my AdMob code, I use

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(MY_TEST_DEVICE_ID);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

When I run the code and I don't specify the test device I usually see a log message in the `LOGCAT` telling me to add my device id using the `addTestDevice` api

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the help.  My old code uses setTesting(), I cut and pasted from it, I guess Googlr must have change there api.